# Mysql and php, wont get all columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code.
For some reason, when I display the html, it wont show the values of the id column. There is a column, but theres no values in it. In the mysql table, there are three columns: "id", "username" and "password". 
Can anybody help me?

```
 include "Connector.php";
        $query = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM users") or die ("MySQL error: " .mysql_error());

        echo "<table>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "
            <tr>
            <td>"
            .$row['id'].
            "</td>
            <td>"
            .$row['username'].
            "</td>
            <td>"
            .$row['password'].
            "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='deleteRow.php?oId=".$row[password]."'>Delete</a></form></td>
        </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysql_free_result($result);
        mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: Isn't `mysql_query($query)`?!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't select the id column:

```
$query = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM users")...
```

you are missing the id column on the mysql_query line. The $query variable isn't used at all.
Let me guess... You copy pasted the code?

Do this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query)....
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM users") or die ("MySQL error: " .mysql_error());
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

No `id` field there.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 queries one of which is actually running. This is the query that is actually running:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM users")
```

You need to add the "id" to that SELECT or just use the $query variable from above.

Answer (score 2):

use this query to find values of all columns:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, password FROM users") or die ("MySQL error: " .mysql_error());